# Getting error while building project using log4j2 in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, log4j, log4j2

I am using maven to build spring boot project using log4j2.
But whenever i run `mvn spring-boot:run`
i get a error like,

```
ERROR Unable to create file /apps/events/logs/event.csv 
Could not create directory /apps/events
```

Why i am getting this error?
Currently on ubuntu.

```
log4j2.xml added in src>main>resources>log4j2.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
<Properties>
<Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
<Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
<PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
</Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<Logger name="com.sample.service" level="debug" additivity="false">
<AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</Logger>

<Root level="info">
<AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

`Update:` I detected a dependecy that is also having a log4j2.xml file configured and gave permission to make directory at the required path and currently no error.

But i want to have my own config(i cannot delete the other config file.)
How do i make log4j2 to use my config file instead of that config?

Comment: `/apps/events/logs/event.csv` isn't a default logging location for Spring Boot so there must be something in your app or logging configuration that you haven't shown here. If you expect your logs to be written to that location, make sure that the user running your app has the necessary permissions to create the necessary directories or use another user to create them in advance. If that location is unexpected, we'll need to see some more of your app to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson There are some remote repositories that i am using (in pom.xml and also i have settings.xml in .m2 repo). I have not mentioned the location anywhere by myself.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson how can i change this location, i currently want to log only on console and NOT on to files.

Comment: Without knowing where it's being configured, it's impossible to say how it can be changed. If you can provide a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve) it should be possible to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson how can i know where it is being configured as i myself have provided only file described in question.

Comment: @RajatAggarwal: enable Log4j2's internal debugging by using the command line switch `-Dlog4j2.debug=true`. This way you can find, which configuration file is used.

Comment: Due to the ordering of the classpath, a `log4j2.xml` file in your own application should hide those in the JAR files.